# BeautifulSoup isn't recognizing UTF-8 characters even after using "fromEncoding=UTF-8"

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup, nltk

I wrote a simple script that just takes a webpage and extracts the contents of it to a tokenized list. However, I'm running into an issue where when I convert the BeautifulSoup object to a String, the UTF-8 characters for ",', etc. won't convert. Instead, they remain in the unicode format.

I'm defining the source as UTF-8 when I create the BeautifulSoup object, and I've even tried running a unicode conversion separately, but nothing works. Any have any idea why this is happening?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk, re, pprint

url = "http://www.bloomberg.com/news/print/2013-07-05/softbank-s-21-6-billion-bid-for-    sprint-approved-by-u-s-.html"
raw = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, fromEncoding="UTF-8")
result = soup.find_all(id="story_content")
str_result = str(result)
notag = re.sub("<.*?>", " ", str_result)
output = nltk.word_tokenize(notag)
print(output)
```

Comment: Wow, it's actually meant to be spelt like that. 'fromEncoding' totally isn't confusing with 'formEncoding'.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the characters that you think aren't converting ? The characters [“] and [’] are not the same as ["] and [']. Are you expecting them to be automatically converted somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters you're having trouble with aren't `"` (U+0022) and `'` (U+0027), they're curly quotes `“` (U+201C) and `”` (U+201D) and `’` (U+2019). Convert those to their straight versions first, and you should get the results you're expecting:

```
raw = urlopen(url).read()
original = raw.decode('utf-8')
replacement = original.replace('\u201c', '"').replace('\u201d', '"').replace('\u2019', "'")
soup = BeautifulSoup(replacement)  # Don't need fromEncoding if we're passing in Unicode
```

That should get the quote characters into the form you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't realize they were two different characters. I tried running the script with your adjustments, but they still aren't being replaced. I even tried searching the for them using

replacement = original.replace(r"\u201c", '"').replace(r"\u201d", '"').replace(r"\u2019", "'")

but that didn't work. Here's what is still showing up in the "replacement" output:

Clearwire\u2019s CEO and president

Comment: Thanks for the help rmunn. Got it working, just had to modify the replacement code to the following:

    replacement = original.replace(u'\u201c', '"').replace(u'\u201d', '"').replace(u'\u2019', "'")

Comment: Whoops, yeah, I forgot that in Python 2.x, string literals weren't Unicode by default and you needed to do `u"foo"` to get a Unicode string. As you've already discovered, you needed to add the `u` in front of those string literals.

Comment: Guess that shows the dangers of writing your code in the Stack Overflow comment box instead of in the Python interpreter... :-)